# Active MQ Web Admin Console Not Working

Tags: java, admin, activemq-classic

Has anyone found a work around or seen the issue of admin console not working in **ActiveMQ 5.4.1** & **5.4.0**?

I'm using the out of the box config. I turned on logging at the DEBUG level and I don't see any jetty startup errors, when I go to http://[myIp]:8161/admin I get this

> HTTP ERROR: 503
>
> Problem accessing /. Reason:
>
> ```
> Service Unavailable
> ```

the log entries Jetty outputs for the request are

> 2010-10-01 14:20:11,599 | DEBUG |
>   REQUEST /favicon.ico on
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$2@ca8e2b8
>   | org.eclipse.jetty.util.log |
>   qtp299878560-27 - /favicon.ico
>   2010-10-01 14:20:11,599 | DEBUG |
>   REQUEST / on
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$2@23bca486
>   | org.eclipse.jetty.util.log |
>   qtp299878560-28 - / 2010-10-01
>   14:20:11,600 | DEBUG | /favicon.ico |
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.log |
>   qtp299878560-27 - /favicon.ico
>   2010-10-01 14:20:11,600 | DEBUG | / |
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.log |
>   qtp299878560-28 - / 2010-10-01
>   14:20:11,621 | DEBUG | REQUEST
>   /favicon.ico on
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$2@38ec029
>   | org.eclipse.jetty.util.log |
>   qtp299878560-29 - /favicon.ico
>   2010-10-01 14:20:11,621 | DEBUG |
>   /favicon.ico |
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.log |
>   qtp299878560-29 - /favicon.ico

I have seen the console work on occasion for the version 5.4.0 but never for 5.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded the JDK to the 64bit version of 1.6.0_21 for Linux and the issue went away so  not sure why an older version of java 6 would create this issue but it works now. I did see a number of people in other forums having this issue though with the current and recent previous versions of active mq, so hopefully this will be a general fix for them as well.